# why the variables get null values when i select them?

Tags: sql

```
   ALTER proc showdetails
@quizid int
as 
begin
   declare @result nvarchar(25)
   declare @fail nvarchar(25)
   declare @grade float


   select distinct eq.Quiz_Title , s.NAME , eq.[Start_Date] , eq.End_Date , eqs.Std_Exam_Grad, @result as r , @fail as f  from Exam_Quiz eq

 inner join SUBJECTS s
   on eq.SubjectId = s.SUB_CODE 
   inner join Exam_Quiz_Student eqs 
   on eqs.Quiz_ID = eq.Quiz_ID 
   where eq.Quiz_ID = @quizid


    set @grade = (select distinct eqs.Std_Exam_Grad  from Exam_Quiz_Student eqs where Quiz_ID = @quizid) 

    if(@grade >= 5)
    begin

      set @result = (select distinct COUNT(Std_NID) + ' ' + Std_Exam_Grad + ' ' + Quiz_ID as G  from Exam_Quiz_Student 
                        group by Std_Exam_Grad , Quiz_ID
                        having Std_Exam_Grad > 5 and Quiz_ID = @quizid) 


      --set @result = (select COUNT(Exam_Quiz_StudentID) as success  from Exam_Quiz_Student)


            --set @result = 'pass'
    end
    if(@grade < 5)
    begin

      set @fail = (select distinct COUNT(Std_NID) + ' ' + Std_Exam_Grad + ' ' + Quiz_ID as G from Exam_Quiz_Student 
                      group by Std_Exam_Grad , Quiz_ID
                      having Std_Exam_Grad < 5 and Quiz_ID = @quizid 

                        ) 


                          --set @fail = (select COUNT(Exam_Quiz_StudentID) from Exam_Quiz_Student)





            --set @fail = 'fail'
    end

end
```

i want to know why the variables return null when i select them i want to know the right way to write variables in sql query statement the stored run right but when i make execute it it return this error message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: `select distinct` won't give you a single record in general. What are you trying to do with those variables exactly?

Comment: i want to select them to get the students who passes the exam in the class so i want to show them

Comment: please i want to know how to resolve this error :

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: If a sub-query returns **more than a single** row, you can't assign it to a **single** variable.

Comment: now i make it return one value but it doesnot work what is the problem ??????

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is why the variables are not having values, you can try TOP 1 like below, to get the value from the first record.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @grade =eqs.Std_Exam_Grad  from Exam_Quiz_Student eqs where Quiz_ID = @quizid
```

But you will be have check if this is OK for the functionality you are trying to achieve.